# Webpack externals without global variable possible?

Tags: webpack, bundle, external

I have a local module `@me/module-a` which exports class `Foo`.
I'm using `npm link` so that in module B I can do:
`import Foo from "@me/module-a";`, and I have `externals:{"@me/module-a":"moduleA"}` in the webpack config of `@me/module-a`.

However this requires me to expose `@me/module-a` as a global variable with `libraryTarget: "var", library: "moduleA"` in the webpack config of the lirbary.

When I do that all works fine, but I'd like to know, is it possible to load the module @me/module-a without it being a global variable?

Edit: I've tried changing to `externals:{"@me/module-a":true}`, but then the bundle of module B tries to load moduleA like this

```
/***/ },
/* 30 */
/***/ function(module, exports) {

module.exports = @me/module-a;

/***/ },
```

which fails with an error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

And still seems to expect a global variable?

Comment: same issue here !
Using `externals: { '@me/module-a' : { commonjs: 'moduleA' } }`
I've got some results but I'm lost with another issue